# Database read/write collision through SQL

Tags: sql, database, visual-studio-2010, ms-access

I have a program written in VB due to the simplicity and GUI when using Visual Studio 2010 as my IDE and compiler. In this program I built a "ticketing" system where approximately 40 users in my center have the authority to submit tickets to my coworkers and I for IT or Facilities assistance.

This system uses an access database on the local server using SQL as the language. The problem is that we have rare occurrences where two users are trying to write a "ticket" at the same time to the database or pull a report of the data at the same time from the database and it crashes on one of users. I use a "try, catch, finally" block to avoid the "unhandled exception error" and have the program setup that should an "unhandled exception error" occur that it closes automatically. The other concern is that once this collision has occurred, the user can no longer read/write to the database through the program until they restart their computer.

With all that in mind, my question is as follows, is there a 100% way to prevent these collisions from occurring (like checking if the database is in use before reading/writing) and if not is there a way to avoid them being locked out of the database until restarting their computer?

Comment: With 40 users you are reaching the limits of MS-Access and must consider

Comment: A full dbms would deal with this better that access, simply because they would be client server. Even then you could get a collision though. That said the fact that you have to restart the machine suggests there's something a bit wrong with the architecture of your application. Sounds like the connection to the db is being left open. You could switch to sql server fairly easily, but disconnected datasets and optimistic locking might be a more fruitful way forward.

Comment: Sorry for the sentence fragment. What version of Access are you using? I assume you are using OLEDB.NET?

Comment: I am using OLEDB as my method of interaction with SQL.  I am using Access 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this post I have swapped to a virtual MySQL database server to run these at much better speeds.  The issue I was having however, was resolved by clearing the pool.  Since at the time I was using OLEDB I used the command:

```
OLEDBConnection.ReleaseObjectPool()
```

and it prevented any more of these computers being locked to where they had to restart the computer as well as help prevent collisions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using OLEDB, you can try using Transactions, which are simple to implement as explained in the Developer Network article entitled [OleDbConnection.BeginTransaction Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93ehy0z8(v=vs.110).aspx).

I must admit I do not understand the IsolationLevel settings, but try omitting it or using the default shown in the example before trying the other available cryptic ones.

As Tony suggests, converting to SQL-Server is a much  more robust (long-term) solution that will ensure data integrity, especially if you plan to add more users. MS has a free migration tool that does an excellent job, even on queries. As for data integrity, see the last paragraph in the Microsoft Support article: [Using Microsoft Jet with IIS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299973)